# How to use both starts_with and ends_with at the same time in one select statement?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, conditional-statements

I want select all columns starting with `fy` and ending with `giving` using `dplyr`. I tried the following code

```
df %>% select(start_with('fy') & ends_with('giving')
```

but it didn't work.

p/s: actually I can hack it with the following chunk

```
df %>% select(starts_with('fy')) %>% select(ends_with('giving'))
```

But I still want to put all the two conditions in one place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using `matches` instead with a regular expression:

```
 df %>% select(matches("^fy.*giving$"))
```

should do the job.

A dummy example using `iris`:

```
iris %>% select(matches("^Pet.*gth$")) %>% colnames
[1] "Petal.Length"
```

Comment: I wasn't either. Then I dedicated some time to learn its grammar (thanks to [this](http://regexr.com/)), it saved me like weeks of work to better enjoy real life, then I turned into a huge regex fan ;-)

Comment: may be I should give it a try :) anyways, thanks for the resource

Answer (score 21):

you can use this:

```
df %>% select(intersect(starts_with('fy') , ends_with('giving')))
```

added same example as @Vincent Bonhomme:

```
iris %>% select(intersect(starts_with("Pet"), ends_with("gth"))) %>% colnames
#[1] "Petal.Length"
```

Comment: I did, but it said I have to wait for 5 minutes