# Combining `starts_with()` and exclusionary `ends_with()` with `intersect()` does not work as expected?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Referring to a previous question and answer - [How to use both starts_with and ends_with at the same time in one select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844863/how-to-use-both-starts-with-and-ends-with-at-the-same-time-in-one-select-stateme)

I am trying the following code below (using tidyverse / dplyr).
For reference, my actual dataset is a lot larger. It's a survey, and I want to select only questions from a certain section, indicated with the letter, but exclude the questions that have text answers - because I am trying to pivot the data to long format.

```
df <- data.frame(D.1 = c(1,1,0,1,1,0),
                 D.2 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0),
                 D.2_TEXT = c("Don't know", NA, "Something else", NA, NA, NA),
                 F.1 = c(0,1,0,0,1,1))
```

The following two selections work fine separately:

```
> select(df, starts_with("D"))

    D.1 D.2       D.2_TEXT
    1   1   1     Don't know
    2   1   1           <NA>
    3   0   0 Something else
    4   1   0           <NA>
    5   1   0           <NA>
    6   0   0           <NA>
```

```
> select(df, !ends_with("_TEXT"))

      D.1 D.2 F.1
    1   1   1   0
    2   1   1   1
    3   0   0   0
    4   1   0   0
    5   1   0   1
    6   0   0   1
```

But when I combine them:

```
> select(df, intersect(starts_with("D"), !ends_with("_TEXT")))

    data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows
```

I know I can do it in two steps:

```
> df %>% 
+  select(starts_with("D")) %>% 
+  select(!ends_with("_TEXT"))

      D.1 D.2
    1   1   1
    2   1   1
    3   0   0
    4   1   0
    5   1   0
    6   0   0
```

But I am puzzled/intrigued why this would not work similar to the question/answer indicated above? Any suggestions / ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your case is slightly different with the link.
You need to select columns that are starts with `D` and not ends with `_Text`.
Thus, `setdiff()` might be what you want.

```
df <- data.frame(D.1 = c(1,1,0,1,1,0),
                 D.2 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0),
                 D.2_TEXT = c("Don't know", NA, "Something else", NA, NA, NA),
                 F.1 = c(0,1,0,0,1,1))

df |> 
  select(setdiff(starts_with("D"), ends_with("_TEXT")))
```

**output**

```
  D.1 D.2
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   0   0
4   1   0
5   1   0
6   0   0
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and it's a good alternative solution (hence the upvote) - but my question is a technical one. I am trying to understand how `intersect()` behaves.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::matches()` to use a more flexible regex:

```
df %>%
  select(matches("^D.*$(?<!_TEXT)", perl = TRUE))
```

Explaining the pattern:

- `^D` starts with "D";
- `.*` has any (including 0) number of other caracters after it;
- And R can't (`!`) find "_TEXT" before (`<`) the end of the string (`$`). `(?...)` being the lookaround sintax

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and it's a good alternative solution (hence the upvote) - but my question is a technical one. I am trying to understand how `intersect()` behaves.